# Performance Optimization when loading term sets

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint, csom

I have a problem with retrieving the terms of a termset in my program (which is written in VB). The termset has about 300 terms, and all of them have about 10 to 70 subterms. I wanted to integrate all the terms in a form, so I used a "Treeview" for this.

I coded the retrieval of the terms like this: 1. Create a new clientContext 2. Load TaxonomySession, then TermStore, then TermGroup and finally the TermSet. The load of the termset looks like this:

```
clientContext.Load(tSet, Function(a As TermSet) a.Terms)
    clientContext.Load(tSet, Function(a As TermSet) a.Name)
```

After that follows an "ExecuteQuery()" And then I have the following:

```
Dim tvroot As System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode = New System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode(tSet.Name)
    orgatree.TopNode = tvroot 'orgatree is the treeview
For Each tterm As Term In tSet.Terms
            clientContext.Load(tterm, Function(w As Term) w.Name)
            clientContext.Load(tterm, Function(w As Term) w.Id)
            clientContext.Load(tterm, Function(w As Term) w.TermsCount)
        Next
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
        Dim tvroot As System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode = New System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode(tSet.Name)
        orgatree.TopNode = tvroot
        For Each tterm As Term In tSet.Terms
            Dim tvanode As System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode = New System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode(tterm.Name)
            tvanode.ToolTipText = tterm.Id.ToString
            tvroot.Nodes.Add(tvanode)
            If tterm.TermsCount <> 0 Then
                treefilling(tvanode, clientContext, tterm) 'a method which is shown in an extra snippet below this one
            End If
        Next
```

And the method "treefilling":

```
Public Function treefilling(parent As System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode, clientContext As ClientContext, term As Term)
    Dim tvnode As System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode
    clientContext.Load(term, Function(w As Term) w.Terms)
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
    For Each tterm As Term In term.Terms
        clientContext.Load(tterm, Function(w As Term) w.Name)
        clientContext.Load(tterm, Function(w As Term) w.Id)
        clientContext.Load(tterm, Function(w As Term) w.TermsCount)
    Next
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
    For Each tterm As Term In term.Terms
        tvnode = New System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode(tterm.Name)
        tvnode.ToolTipText = tterm.Id.ToString
        parent.Nodes.Add(tvnode)
        ' clientContext.ExecuteQuery()
        If tterm.TermsCount <> 0 Then
            treefilling(tvnode, clientContext, tterm)
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

**And now to the problem**

This code is not very fast. It needs up to 3 or 4 minutes to load all data. I've already tried to optimize it. Earlier versions had much more unnecessary "executeQuery()" lines. But the program is still to slow. *Is there a faster way to load all the data of a termset and integrate it in a form (for example in a treeview)?*

Comment: This is off-topic here. Better post this kind of questions in Code Review (http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you load the data in a form or whatever is irrelevant.  What's relevant is the process of getting terms via the SharePoint 2013 CSOM.  Remember, the CSOM is a wrapper for sending Xml requests back and forth between the client and the SharePoint 2013 server.

So, use multiple threads to load multiple terms/termsets at the same time.  You'll need to write thread-safe code that retrieves where several threads simultaneously query the managed meta data service via the client object model, being careful to limit the total number of requests to some reasonable number (say 8 requests at a time) as not to overload the server.

Multiple threads accessing the server can work because this is a READ operation.